# Can a java8 compiled jar file run on java7?

Tags: java

I have a jar file in that some features only belong to `java 8`(for ex lambda expression), so it is compiled in `java 8`. Same jar has some features belong to both `java 7` and `java 8`. Now i want that when user run this jar in `java 7` , `java 7` related classes should work as he/she only wants functionality that work on `java 7` only. If he/she wants the functionality related to java 8  , he will run it with `java 8`.

This `java 8` compiled jar should not give an error of  "*Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above*". And i don't want to create separate jars for `java 8` and `java 7` users.

Comment: No you will have to create two jars one for java8 and another for java7 runtime ... please check  -source, -target  javac options

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, multi-release jars allow this, they are a new feature in Java 9, but multi-release jars do not go back to java 7, however they will work for future java releases.

[Multi-release Jars](https://www.voxxed.com/2016/11/java-9-series-multi-release-jar-files/)